# java equivalent of assert( 0 && "description")

Tags: java, assert

What is the Java equivalent this?

```
assert(0 && "description");
```

I've tried

```
assert(false && "description");
```

But Java types are too strict for that. Any tips on the idiomatic way to add a description to an assert statement?

Comment: What is that supposed to do? `"description"` is not a boolean value. What case are you trying to "assert"?

Comment: in c++ one would often write a description of what was violated in the assert. For instance, `assert(0 && "one should not get here ...");`

Comment: in c++ when the assertion is hit, the description will be printed to screen, helping in debug by describing what bad thing just happened

Comment: Hopefully you don't think Java's assert mechanism is used for the same things as in C++. It's definitely not for regular debugging which seems to be your goal.

Comment: Are you maybe looking for e.g. `Objects.requireNonNull()` or something similar where you can provide a message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a description to an assertion using:

```
assert false : "description";
```

This is described as

```
assert Expression1 : Expression2 ;
```

on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html